# What is the equation that minimizes both $\theta$ and $d$ at the same time?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I am wondering how can we minimize $\theta$ and $d$ in this figure? $\theta$ is the angle between the line passing from a point in the circle $p$ to a point on the circumference and the tangent of the circle at that point. $d$ of course is a variable which can be changed. I tried to figure out how I can represent $d$ as a function of $r$, the radius of the circle and $\theta$ and then differentiate with respect to $\theta$ but I could not find a formula. Any thought to solve it?

Comment: The shortest path from $p$ to the circumference is along the radius $r$. So $\theta=90^\circ$.

Comment: TonyK:  Of course.

Comment: But $\theta$ is not minimum then!

Comment: Your question is a bit incoherent. Unless $p$ is the circle’s center, there’s exactly one point on the circumference that minimizes $d$, and at that point $|\theta|=\pi/2$. For any other value of $\theta$, $d$ is necessarily larger, so there’s exactly one value of $\theta$ that minimizes $d$, and it is trivially the minimum such value. It simply doesn’t make sense to speak of the minimal value of $\theta$ that minimizes $d$, so perhaps you should clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just want to minimize both $\theta$ and $d$ at the same time not just $d$.

Comment: @Isaacadel That doesn't really make sense. Do you want to minimise $\theta + d$?

Comment: Among all possible $\theta$s and $d$s, I want the one that minimize them altogether, not just each one at a time.

Comment: In other words, I wish to have the best compromise of getting a smaller $\theta$ without letting $d$ to become longer.

Comment: Define a utility function that quantifies this tradeoff that you’re willing to make between $d$ and $\theta$, and minimize that.

Comment: But what is the closed form relation between $\theta$ and $d$, given $r$ and the distance from $p$ to the center? If I have this, I would minimize $\theta$ given a constraint function of $d$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Given a point $(p,q)$ inside, or outside, of a circle. Draw the line passing through the point $(p,q)$ and the centre of the circle. This line will meet the circle in two points, and be normal to the circle at these two points. One of the points will be the closest point on the circle to $(p,q)$. The other will be the furthest from $(p,q)$.

Here is a short proof:

Consider the unit circle with parametric equations $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$ where $0 \le t < 2\pi$.

Let $(p,q)$ be a fixed point in the plane and consider the vector joining $(p,q)$ to $(\cos t,\sin t)$:

$${\bf s}(t) = (p-\cos t){\bf i} + (q-\sin t){\bf j}$$

The length of ${\bf s}$ is given by
$$\|{\bf s}\| = \sqrt{(p-\cos t)^2+(q-\sin t)^2}$$
If $\|{\bf s}\| > 0$, i.e. $(p,q)$ does not lie on the circle, then a maximum (resp. minimum) of $\|{\bf s}\|$ corresponds to a maximum (resp. minimum) of $\|{\bf s}\|^2$. Hence, consider
$$\|{\bf s}\|^2 =  (p-\cos t)^2+(q-\sin t)^2$$
Differentiating with respect to $t$ gives 
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\|{\bf s}\|^2 = 2(p\sin t - q\cos t)$$
Hence, there is a maximum/minimum of $\|{\bf s}\|^2$ if, and only if, $p\sin t - q\cos t=0$, i.e. $$(p,q) \propto (\cos t,\sin t)$$
This means that $(p,q)$ lies on the line passing through $(0,0)$ and $(\cos t, \sin t)$. This line corresponds to a diameter of the circle.

**Recall that diameters meet the circumference at right angles.**

Comment: But $t$ in your answer is the angle from a point on the circle to the origin of the circle, unlike the angle in my question!

Comment: Sorry for this, but I just edited the question to make it more clear. In the new edition, I just want to minimize both $\theta$ and $d$ not just $d$.